# How can I show the correct value in a javascript array element?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

In the following code, I create a car object and modify an element by increasing the count. Each time I modify the car, I push it onto an array called yada. At the end, I access the 3rd car that gets put onto the yada array to see what the count is, but it reports a count of 6 instead of what I expected to be a count of 3.

```
<html>
<body>
<script>

var car = {limit:4, count:0, trigger:0};
var yada = new Array();

for(var i=0; i<6; i++)
{
    car.count += 1;
    if(car.count >= car.limit)
    {
        car.trigger = 1;

    }
    yada.push(car);
    alert(car.count+" "+car.limit+" "+car.trigger);
};

alert(yada[2].count + " TEST ");

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: there is only one `car`

Comment: you're pushing multiple times the reference to the same car. So all the elements in the array are exactly one element - a reference to a car object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is important to understand the difference between pass by value and pass by reference: [Is JavaScript a pass-by-reference or pass-by-value language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language).

Javascript's default is always pass by value, but for objects the value of the variable is a reference. Because of this, when you pass an object and change its members, those changes persist outside of the function.

You could adapt by making a new car object within your for loop:

```
<html>
<body>
<script>


var yada = new Array();

for(var i=0; i<6; i++)
{
    let car = {limit:4, count:0, trigger:0};
    car.count = i+1;
    if(car.count >= car.limit)
    {
        car.trigger = 1;

    }
    yada.push(car);
    alert(car.count+" "+car.limit+" "+car.trigger);
};

alert(yada[2].count + " TEST ");

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Because you declare the car a local variable, it doesn't persist outside the loop and you create a new one every looprun that you can then store in your array.

This works for me.

Comment: Variables are function scoped, your car variable exists out of the for loop

Comment: True, for correctness I changed it to let. Still, the code works.

Answer (score 1):

There is only one `car` object which you push everytime into your array, so all 6 entries in `yada` point to the same car object, and change in any one of them is reflected across all the "pointers" or array entries.

You loop through and increment `car.count` 6 times and when you are done with the loop you access the `count` of `car` in the array, which points to the same `car` object which has now `car.count` equal to 6 and that's what you see. No matter which array index you access, you will get the same result.

Perhaps, you want to create multiple `car` objects, have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new

Your constructor function could look something like this:

```
function Car() {
    this.limit = 4;
    this.count = 0;
    this.trigger = 0;
}
```

Then, to create a new `car` object you can just say :

```
var myCar = new Car();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is only one `car` with multiple references to it in your array. You need to create a new object from the current `car`.

```js
var car = {limit:4, count:0, trigger:0};
var yada = new Array();

for(var i=0; i<6; i++)
{
    car.count += 1;
    if(car.count >= car.limit)
    {
        car.trigger = 1;
    }
    yada.push(Object.assign({},car) );
};
console.log(yada);
```